# How to access html element label without an ID or class?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the value by innerHtml property of label.

```
<span class="input-container">

    <input type="checkbox"  name="opt-in" id="opt-in" class="checkbox opt-in" value="1235454905" />

    <label for="opt-in"> We may collect, use and process data according to our Privacy Policy</label>

</span>
```

I can't add id or class to the level because it's a WordPress short code form. Is there any way? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use the `label` tag, or by attribute `for='opt-in'` or `label of parent` to get label's `innerHTML`

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("label").innerHTML);
console.log(document.querySelector("label[for='opt-in']").innerHTML);
console.log(document.querySelector("#opt-in").parentElement.querySelector("label").innerHTML);
```

```html
<span class="input-container">

    <input type="checkbox"  name="opt-in" id="opt-in" class="checkbox opt-in" value="1235454905" />

    <label for="opt-in"> We may collect, use and process data according to our Privacy Policy</label>

</span>
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you so much!
PS. 

    console.log(document.querySelector("label").innerHTML); 

should not be used since it will hit the first label tag of the page

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName("label")[0]` will select the first label element on the page. This approach only works if you know exactly where the element is in your HTML.

Comment: This is tough to measure. Anyway, Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can get the span by using `document.getElementsByClassName()` Notic that this method will return an `Array`, so you will have to access the first component, if there's only one element with that `ClassName`.
After that, you can get the label by `document.getElementsByClassName()[0].childNodes[1]`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you can add the class or id by going in WordPress admin page => appearance => editor.
there you can add class or id using the WordPress editor.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can select an element sing any of the attributes, and wrapping it in square braces. JQuery is required for this.

In your case you could use `("[for=opt-in")` or `("label[for=opt-in")`

If the element has a name you could also use `("[name=element_name")`

Take a look here for some of the available methods, as well as the square brackets.
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Comment: I am using JS. Thanks for the help!